# ProgressDialog.setMessage(String) doesn't throw IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, view, illegalstateexception

I am calling `Progressdialog.setMessage(String)` method from a worker Thread in the following code but Android doesn't throw `IllegalStateException` which should say "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling View methods on another thread than the UI thread" because I am modifying UI from outside the UI thread which is forbidden in Android.

Here is the runnable of my worker thread as an inner class :

```
public class HostOnHoldRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
            hostOnHoldDialog.setMessage("Game is on hold because the host paused the app (" + currentTimeLeftForHostOnHoldTimeOut / 1000 + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: hostOnHoldDialog is the `ProgressDialog` member of my Activity.

Instead of throwing `IllegalStateException`, android just doesn't update the UI according to the message.

Is this a bug?

If I use runOnUiThread in the `Runnable`, everything works fine e.g.

```
public class HostOnHoldRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
             public void run() { 
            hostOnHoldDialog.setMessage("Game is on hold because the" + 
            " host paused the app (" + 
            currentTimeLeftForHostOnHoldTimeOut / 1000 + ")");

             }
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: post traceable codes sir, and shouldn't you be happy? or you want your app to crash? well that wil be easy, but seriously post enough codes

Comment: Thank you but I couldn't find anything else to share, i am just calling handler.postDelayed(new HostOnHoldRunnable(), 1000); 
If I use runOnUiThread, everything works fine (I added additional code in the original post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, you see `Handler` works with `Looper` for running messages, Handler runs on the UI thread, every View has a handler attached to it, that enables it to post methods/functions on the UI thread, any newly created Thread that wants to run messages or run on the UI thread has to call a Handler or Looper.prepare() which later handler will be implemented.  On a multi-threaded app, the use of Handler().post() or Handler().postDelayed() or View.post() or View.postDelayed() or Context.getMainLooper() are all functions that aid you to post on UI thread, so if you call methods with this approach you will not get an exception. so there is not problem or bug here, just read some few lines of the Docs on Looper, Hanlder and View

Comment: what this? no but if you read the docs you will even come up with a better understanding @EnesBattal

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            hostOnHoldDialog.setMessage("Game is on hold because the host paused the app (" + currentTimeLeftForHostOnHoldTimeOut / 1000 + ")");
        }
    });
```